# How to deal with relative paths in input files?

Tags: input, tex-general

Say I have a a file `File1.tex` that I input in a file like `Foo.tex`:

`folder1/File1.tex`:

```
\begin{frame}
    This is file 1.
\end{frame}
```

`Foo.tex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \input{folder1/File1.tex}
 
\end{document}
```

All works fine. But if I include a graphic in `File1` the relative path does not work in `Foo.tex":

Say I add a file `image1.jpg` to folder `folder1/images/`.

Now I can extend `folder1/File1.tex`:

```
\begin{frame}
    This is file 1.
    \includegraphics{images/image1}
\end{frame}
```

But now, `Foo.tex` could not find the graphic, because of its point of view, the path of `\includegraphics` should be `folder1/images/image1`.

How can I manage such things?

Comment: paths are relative to the working directory of the latex process, not relative to any file

Comment: Yeah, I know.. But I am looking for an elegant way to extend the solution (to mention the folder name `folder1` within the `File1.tex`). What is, if I change the folder name, I would have to edit all `include graphics` tags.

Comment: I would just use `\includegraphics{image1}`  just as you use `\documentclass{article}` keep the ppaths out of the documemnt and just use teh TEXINPUTS path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either

**1.** Always type the directory starting from the position of `Foo.tex`, since the relative path in `\includegraphics` from an `input` file cannot be used anywhere anyways.

or

**2.** Declare all the possible image folders at the beginning of your main file using

```
...
\usepackage{graphicx)
\graphicspath{ {./folder1/images/}{./folder2/images/}... }
...
```

and later only specify the files' names

```
\includegraphics{image1}
```

Comment: The first approach isn't perfect, because if I would rename a folder, I have to edit each `\includegraphics` tag.. But the second one is really good. Did not know this one.. Perfect solution. Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice if LaTeX would support not only paths relative to the working directory  but also relative to the file where the respective path is found/specified in.
From the answer I assume this cannot be achieved so far?!