# nested relative inputs

Tags: input, relative

**Problem:**
This is something that that bothered me for quite a time. If you have multiple files, then you have to make all `input` paths relative to the `main` tex file (or actually the directory from where you compile the `main` file) and not relative to the file that calls the `input`.

**Appearances:**
There are also others that expected that the paths are meant to be relative to the current path
[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153751/relative-paths-for-input-and-building-from-different-directories), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596780/using-relative-path-in-input-and-includegraphics-commands), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588772/how-to-deal-with-relative-paths-in-input-files), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/how-to-make-the-main-file-recognize-relative-paths-used-in-the-imported-files?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39083/input-files-in-different-directories)

**Packages:**
I am aware of the [`import`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/import) package. However, I think it is strange that there different commands for different levels. Also the [`subfiles`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfiles) can be used for relative paths.

**Conclusion:** Nevertheless, I thought there should be an elementary solution. Hence, I finally came up with a really short solution.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is what I wanted to say with "(or actually the directory from where you compile the `main` file)", i.e., this directory does not need to be the directory where the `main` file is located. However, in most cases this will be the directory of the `main` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

One possible solution that uses the LaTeX3 "data types" is actually very simple. It can be nested arbitrarily many times.
I guess this solution can be further improved by people with sophisticated skills, so feel free to improve it and use it in other packages.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_relinput_stack_seq
\tl_new:N \g_relinput_dump_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\relinput}{O{./}m}{
  % add the new relative input to the history path
  \seq_put_right:Nn \g_relinput_stack_seq {#1}
  % input the file
  \input{\seq_use:Nn \g_relinput_stack_seq {} #2}
  % remove the new relative input from the history
  \seq_gpop_right:NN \g_relinput_stack_seq \g_relinput_dump_tl
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

I am not even sure, if the dump variable is needed, but `\seq_gpop_right:NN` wants two arguments.
Clearly, this can easily be extended for the `\include` command. Just by adding

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\relinclude}{O{./}m}{
  % add the new relative input to the history path
  \seq_put_right:Nn \g_relinput_stack_seq {#1}
  % input the file
  \include{\seq_use:Nn \g_relinput_stack_seq {} #2}
  % remove the new relative input from the history
  \seq_gpop_right:NN \g_relinput_stack_seq \g_relinput_dump_tl
}
```

## Example

The usage is very simple. Lets us say we have the following folder structure

```
src/
   main.tex
   chapter1/
      chapter1.tex
      tikz/
         tikz-picture.tex
   chapter2/
      chapter2.tex
      big-table.tex
```

Then in the main file `main.tex` we have

```
...
\begin{document}

\relinput[./chapter1]{chapter1}
\relinput[./chapter2]{chapter2}
...
\end{document}
```

In `chapter1.tex`

```
...
\relinput[./tikz]{tikz-picture}
...
```

In `chapter2.tex`

```
...
\relinput{big-table} % \relinput[./]{big-table} would also work
...
```